# Insert emoji/text at the end of the text in a contenteditable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to insert an emoji in the content editable area. But whenever I am trying to insert, it is inserted at the start of the line.

i am using

here is my code example

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.fg-emoji-picker-item', function(){
    var emoji = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var el = jQuery('.advanced-th-bp-activity-form');
    el.focus();
    pasteHTMLAtCaret(emoji);
});
```

and the pasteHTMLAtCaret function is

```
function pasteHTMLAtCaret(html, selectPastedContent) {
    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            console.log(frag);
            while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            var firstNode = frag.firstChild;
            range.insertNode(frag);
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                if (selectPastedContent) {
                    range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
                } else {
                    range.collapse(true);
                }
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        var originalRange = sel.createRange();
        originalRange.collapse(true);
        sel.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
        if (selectPastedContent) {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", originalRange);
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Look the emojis are inserted into the first, thought those emojies were entered after the text.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It is obvious you are not happy with the emoji being inserted at the beginning, but you don't say what the desired location is. If you just want to insert the emoji at the end, you shouldn't need 25 lines of selection-manipulation logic: you could just append the emoji to the current field value. So, it seems your goal must be different, but you don't say what it is, and it is not clear from reading the code sample.

Comment: @Tom no one wants emoji only at the end. Because of how JS Range is structured, it requires lot of codes just to put emoji at caret position, and to keep the caret immediately after. You'll see in web that inserting emoji take almost a second to appear. I made a complex ContentEditable div capable of handling Mention Span and Emoji Text. Difficult because: 1- browsers added more childNodes on insertion, 2- You lose caret position on focusout to go out for emoji picker, 3- Range API contains separate range for each childNode that you have to sum up until you find real child position of caret.

Answer (score 0):

You `selection` is wrong! It's pointing to start of text rather than the point where `emoji` need to be inserted